# Clearing OS Cache

Tags: partitioning, wine, home-directory, cache

I'm guessing that's what it is.  I reinstalled Ubuntu and replaced my newly created home directory with my old home directory.  Problem is, my new Ubuntu doesn't have XYZ program installed and when I double click a file it attempts to open it with XYZ program.  How do I 'reset' my home partition so that it won't use non-existent programs?

Specifically, its WINE.  It wants me to open files with internet explorer and notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with a text editor remove all entries pointing to non-existent programs.

Just remove the file if you want to use the default settings for all file types.